# Error.I can't figure it out

Tags: visualforce

```
public with sharing class ContactViewController {
     private final String NEW_CONTACT_PAGE = '/apex/NewContact';

    //list of Contacts
    public  List<Contact__c> contactsList  {get; private set;}
    //list of fields to be getted from database (for ordering logic)
    private List<String>  contactsFieldList {get; private set;}
    // total count records
    private integer contactsListCount   {get;set;}
    // offset for pagination
    private integer contactsListOffset  {get;set;}
    // ordering
    public  integer orderIndex     {get;set;}
    // order direction
    private String  orderDirection {get;set;}
    private integer prevOrderIndex  = 0;
    // pagination
    public  final integer PAGE_SIZE_DEFAULT_INDEX = 1; 
    public  List<SelectOption>  pageSizeItems {get; private set;}
    public  integer pageSize    {get;set;}
    public  integer pageCount   {get;set;}
    public  integer currentPage {get;set;} 
    // for deleting and searching commands
    public String contactId    {get;set;}
    public String searchString {get;set;}



   //constructor without standatd controller
   public ContactViewController(){

       // create fields list
            this.contactsFieldList = new List<String>{ 'Name',
                                                      'Email__c',
                                                  'Contact_Level__c', 
                                                  'Account__c', 
                                                  'Owner__c', 
                                                  'Created_By__c', 
                                                  'Created_Date__c'
                                                        };


        //create count items per page allowable values list
        this.pageSizeItems = new List<SelectOption>{new SelectOption('5','5'),
                                                    new SelectOption('10','10'),
                                                    new SelectOption('20','20'),
                                                    new SelectOption('50','50'),
                                                    new SelectOption('100','100')};
   }   
    // make new list of contactsList using pagination and ordering    
    private void getContactsList(){
        //refrech total records 
        getTotalRecords();
        // notnalize value to '' if null
        this.searchString = (searchString==null) ? '' : searchString;
        // calculate current page
        this.currentPage=contactsListOffset+1;
        // fetch records from database
        this.contactsList = Database.query('SELECT '+
                                  String.join(contactsFieldList, ',')+
                                  ' FROM Contact__c '+
                                  ' WHERE firstName like \'%'+searchString+'%\' OR lastName like \'%'+searchString+'%\' '+ 
                                  ' ORDER BY '+contactsFieldList.get(orderIndex)+' '+orderDirection+
                                  ' LIMIT '+pageSize+
                                  ' OFFSET '+contactsListOffset*pageSize);
    }

    // get total count of records
    private void getTotalRecords(){
        // notnalize value to '' if null
        this.searchString = (searchString==null) ? '' : searchString;     
        // fetch total count from database
        this.contactsListCount = Database.countQuery('select count() FROM Owner '+' WHERE firstName like \'%'+searchString+'%\' OR lastName like \'%'+searchString+'%\' ');       
        // calculate page count
        this.pageCount = ((contactsListCount / pageSize)*pageSize!=contactsListCount)
            ? (contactsListCount / pageSize+1) : (contactsListCount / pageSize);
        // show message if no recirds found
        if(contactsListCount==0 && ApexPages.currentPage()!=null){
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.WARNING,'No records found'));
        }
    }     
       // get records for first page
    public void first(){
        this.contactsListOffset = 0;
        //rebuild contacts list
        getContactsList();
    }
      // get records for previous pages
    public void prev(){
        this.contactsListOffset = (contactsListOffset>0) ? contactsListOffset-1 : contactsListOffset;
        //rebuild contacts list
        getContactsList();
    }

    //get records for next page
    public void next(){
        this.contactsListOffset = ((contactsListOffset+1)*pageSize<contactsListCount)
            ? contactsListOffset+1 : contactsListOffset;
        //rebuild contacts list
        getContactsList();
    }

    //get records for last pages
    public void end(){
        contactsListOffset = contactsListCount / pageSize;
        this.contactsListOffset = (contactsListOffset*pageSize==contactsListCount && contactsListOffset>0)
            ? contactsListOffset-1 : contactsListOffset;
        //rebuild contacts list
        getContactsList();
    }

    // set order and order direction
    public void setOrderIndex(){
        if(prevOrderIndex==orderIndex){
            if('ASC'.equals(orderDirection))
                this.orderDirection = 'DESC';
            else
                this.orderDirection = 'ASC';
        } else {
            this.prevOrderIndex=orderIndex;
            this.orderDirection = 'ASC';
        }
        //rebuild contacts list
        getContactsList();
    }

    // delele decord
    public void del(){
        if(contactId==null)
            return;
        // get contact by Id
        Contact cnt = [select Id from contact where Id = :contactId];
        // delete contact
        delete cnt;
        if(ApexPages.currentPage()!=null){
                ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO,'Contact #'+contactId+' was deleted'));
        }
        //rebuild contacts list
        getContactsList();
    }

    // search and show records
    public void search(){
        this.contactsListOffset = 0;
        //rebuild contacts list
        getContactsList();
    }

    // re init count items per page
    public void setItemsPerPage(){
        //rebuild contacts list
        getContactsList();
    }

    // redirect to new contact page
    public PageReference newContact(){
        PageReference pr = new PageReference(NEW_CONTACT_PAGE);
        pr.setRedirect(true);  
        return pr;
    }
```

}

Tell me why it does not populate the table?

```
<!-- Contacts list block -->
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Contacts Information" collapsible="false" columns="1"> 
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!contactsList}" var="item" id="contactTable">
```

Comment: I'm a newbie not quite sure what that means

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot possibly have a custom object `Contact__c` possessing the standard fields `FirstName` and `LastName`:

```
    this.contactsList = Database.query('SELECT '+
                              String.join(contactsFieldList, ',')+
                              ' FROM Contact__c '+
                              ' WHERE firstName like \'%'+searchString+'%\' OR lastName like \'%'+searchString+'%\' '+
```

Possibly you mean `FROM Contact` here.

In general, please make an effort to debug your own code and provide SFSE with details of what's going on. Here, that might mean output from `System.debug()` lines at different points in your code to understand which of your instance variables are populated where, confirmation that your query (given the actual parameters you're using on the page) returns a non-empty result set, and of course the verbatim text and line locations of any errors.